# RDC in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, remote-desktop

Is there any third party control available to connect remote desktop in asp.net web page.

Which one is best to use on asp.net application.

Answer (score 0):

Pass this code to an HTML File and if you want you can divide it later no an ASP.net aspx file separating the HTML and Code Behind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Check out the minimal requirements to client machine.

Comment: I have Used tried using this but not works for me.. Pls suggest me any other 3rd party controls to do RDC in asp.net web application pages